# how to load datatable from datarow array?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow[] dr = (DataTable)dsData.Tables[0].Select("Some Criteria");
dt = (DataTable)dsData.Tables[0].clone();
dt.Rows.Add(dr); //line causing the error
```

The above code is throwing an error in bolded line as follows

```
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type  
'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store in pipelinesubstatusid Column. 
Expected type is Decimal."
```

can you help me to overcome the problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach(var row in dr)
{
    var r=dt.NewRow();
    r.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
    dt.Rows.Add(r);
}
```

or

```
foreach(var row in dr)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```